# how do I order eager relationship using with()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to order

```
Content::with('blocks.settings')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

blocks by a 'order' column, how can I do that?

i am aware of this approach:

```
with(array('model' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('result', 'DESC');
    }))
```

but I am not sure how that would work in my case? I am using nested eager loading and it seems to me that above approach will only work for single level eager load?

Can someone give me an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add constraint on `blocks` model,

```
Content::with(array(
    'blocks.settings' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order', 'DESC'); // this constraint works on blocks model
    }    
))->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

If you want to add constraints on `settings` model, try this

```
Content::with(array(
    'blocks'=> function($query) {
        $query->with(array(
                    'settings'=> function($query) {
                        $query->orderBy('order', 'DESC'); // this constraint works on blocks model
                    }    
                ))
              ->ordery('order', 'DESC'); // this constraint works on blocks model
    }    
))->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
Content::with(array(
    'blocks' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('order', 'DESC');
    }, 
    'blocks.settings'
))->where('slug', $slug)->first();;
```

First we tell it to load blocks and order them by the `order` column. Second element in the array also tells to load settings with all the blocks.